# Google drive api - com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.files() - None of the File objects have permissions?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

When using the **google drive api**

I use `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.files()` to iterate some files.

I noticed None of the Directory objects have permissions?

When I use the File objects, the `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getPermissions()` method always returns `null`.

**Is there some way I can get this list method to return the permissions as well?**

**Otherwise I'll have to pummel the google api?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `fields` option to include `permissions`?
I don't generally use the Java SDK, but I think look into [setFields()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.Get.html#setFields(java.lang.String))

Comment: So I used to go
`this.drive.files().get(id).execute();`
Now i have to go
`this.drive.files().get(id).setFields(fields).execute();`
Is there a way to get all the default fields?

Comment: There should always be a default set of fields, but what I did was just set up the fields string for all of the ones we actually use and explicitly use it every request

Comment: Me neither. They've changed at least once, best to be explicit for the fields you need

Comment: all i know is permissions is NOT default. thanks for all the time